# std::stod(string, &pos) - Difference between &pos and only pos

Tags: c++, std

I want to get the position of the next character (+) after getting the first number (45345.3).

Why does only `&pos` work here? First, I tried to use only `pos` but it does not work.

```
string term = "45345.3+24";
unsigned int pos = 0;
double number = stod(term, &pos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the declaration of `stod` is as follows:

```
double stod (const string &str, size_t *idx = 0);
double stod (const wstring &str, size_t *idx = 0);
```

In other words, `idx` is a *pointer* to a value that's meant to receive information if desired. So, when passing a value it needs to *be* a pointer, such as `&pos`.

It's possible that it could have used a reference, which would allow you to use `pos` without the ampersand. However, that would have disallowed the possibility of using a null pointer to state that you didn't *want* the information.

Since it's basically modeled after the original C `strtod` function (also in the C++ `<cstdlib>` header), that's a use-case that's been preserved from there.

Comment: Thanks :D I am new to c++ and I need to understand what pointers are. I also discovered that just pos works after making pos a constexpr (which does not make any sense).

Comment: @Bubble: Making `pos` a `constexpr` works for exactly the same reason that `stod(str, 0)` works... A `0` literal is a valid null-pointer constant.  Without `constexpr` it wasn't a compile-time constant, and so it wasn't eligible for interpretation as a null-pointer constant.  What it's not doing is providing the variable `pos` as the place to store `idx`... as you can easily test by writing `constexpr unsigned pos = 42;` instead of `0`, which will also prevent it from being a null-pointer constant.